# Xpath query expression: summing up a attribute over a condition

Tags: xpath

```
<Cities>
   <city>
        <name />
        <country />
        <population asof = "2019" />
            <total> 2918695</total>
            <Average_age> 28 </Average_age>
   </city>
   <city>
        <name />
        <country />
        <population asof = "2020" />
            <total> 78805467 </total>
            <Average_age> 32 </Average_age>
   </city>
</Cities>
```

I want to build a Xpath query which returns the total population of cities where asof is higher than 2018

Comment: Are you sure that `population` should be an empty element?  Your indentation implies hierarchy that's not actually there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
sum(/Cities/city[population/@asof > 2018]/total)
```

Or, another, less specific, version:

```
sum(//city[population/@asof > 2018]/total)
```

Answer (score 0):

the expression to grab population with `asof` attribute greater than 2018 would be:

```
//population[@asof > '2018']
```

- If you looking for `<total>` which is a sibling of `<population>` despite your indentation use `following-sibling::total` after the expression
- otherwise use `/total`

lets follow the first approach so the XPath continues as:

```
//population[@asof > '2019']/following-sibling::total
```

and add `/text()` at the end to get text inside of desired `<total>` tag. additionally if you want sum of populations you can put the whole expression inside `sum()` function. the inside expression of sum gonna be like:

```
//population[@asof > '2019']/following-sibling::total/text()
```